# Symbian C++ stdint seamingly random errors

Tags: c++, symbian, s60, pys60, symbian3

I am trying to compile the PyS60USB for Pys60 2.0 with the Symbian Belle Sdk but for some seemingly unrelated reason I am getting the seemingly random errors about almost everything not naming a type, like these:

*

```
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:38: error: '__int8_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:43: error: '__int16_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:48: error: '__int32_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:53: error: '__int64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:58: error: '__uint8_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:63: error: '__uint16_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:68: error: '__uint32_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:73: error: '__uint64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:77: error: '__int_least8_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:78: error: '__int_least16_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:79: error: '__int_least32_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:80: error: '__int_least64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:82: error: '__uint_least8_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:83: error: '__uint_least16_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:84: error: '__uint_least32_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:85: error: '__uint_least64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:87: error: '__int_fast8_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:88: error: '__int_fast16_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:89: error: '__int_fast32_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:90: error: '__int_fast64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:92: error: '__uint_fast8_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:93: error: '__uint_fast16_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:94: error: '__uint_fast32_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:95: error: '__uint_fast64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:97: error: '__intmax_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:98: error: '__uintmax_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:101: error: '__intptr_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/stdint.h:102: error: '__uintptr_t' does not name a type*
```

I also  get other errors like these:
*

```
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/python25/pyport.h:90: error: 'uintptr_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/python25/pyport.h:91: error: 'intptr_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/python25/pyport.h:116: error: 'Py_intptr_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/_sigset.h:51: error: '__uint64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/_timeval.h:35: error: '__suseconds_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/_timeval.h:40: error: '__time_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/_timeval.h:47: error: redefinition of 'struct timeval'
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/libc/sys/time.h:30: error: previous definition of 'struct timeval'
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/select.h:45: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef __fd_mask fd_mask'
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/libc/sys/types.h:89: error: 'fd_mask' has a previous declaration as 'typedef long int fd_mask'
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/select.h:50: error: '__uint64_t' does not name a type
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/select.h:72: error: redefinition of 'struct fd_set'
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/libc/sys/types.h:97: error: previous definition of 'struct fd_set'
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/select.h:74: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/stdapis/sys/select.h:74: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef int fd_set'
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0/epoc32/include/libc/sys/types.h:99: error: 'fd_set' has a previous declaration as 'typedef struct fd_set fd_set'*
```

**ETC...**

I am guessing these errors are probably related and are probably caused by some problem with my environment or something. Do any of you have any I idea what could possibly causing all these hundreds of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two incompatible C standard library implementations in your include path. There's the old `ESTLIB` in `epoc32/include/libc` and the newer Open C `epoc32/include/stdapis`. Remove the former from your MMP file include paths. While there, check that you are not linking against `estlib.lib`.

Disclaimer: It's been a couple of years since I last time touched a Symbian SDK.